# Add date range or disable date in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to create date range for leave application form. Is there any way to add date range or disable date after users choose the date in Google Form?

Comment: Please add brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén I mean using Google Form, is there any ways to manipulate the date option? In google form, they do have date option to add in the form but it just simple date picker. So can we change the date option to become date range picker or disable date that we want so users can't choose the date.

Comment: Nowadays it's not possible.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Do you mean that you would only allow the users to pick between a defined range of dates (for example only dates within one month)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could Make it like this:

Title of form

Description (make sure to add how long they are allowed to take off)

Question 1: When are you going to start taking leave?

Date

Question 2: When will you go back to work.

Date

I don't think you can put a restriction of time on the calendar. But you could tell them how long they can take off in the description.

I hope this helps you with you problem, and I hope you have a wonderful rest of your day.

Comment: Thanks Izzy, but that's the things that I try to avoid because if create 2 date option, if users want to apply leave further in the future, for example March 2021, usually they will forget to change date for second date option so it will become from March 2021 until September 2020. So if can make date range or disable date after the first date option it will be good.

Comment: For that, the best thing to do is to put a reminder to make sure they have the right dates. But I hope you are able to solve your problem.

Comment: I just thought of something. It might be a little late. But you could make a text box where they write out the date in it.